# How to insert these matrices in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

[image]I wanna ask how to insert these matrices in Mathematica when the dimension is (2N+6) by (2N+6). I think we can insert it if we can rewrite it as a block matrix where the entries are 2 by 2 matrices and then use "ArrayFlatten".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
data = Array[a, {3, 2, 2}];
n = 6;
helper = Join[data, ConstantArray[0, n]];
A = ArrayFlatten[
   RotateRight[helper, #] & /@ Range[0, n]
   ]
```

You merely have to replace the matrix `data` by $V_{m,1}$ etc.